# Weird file_get_contents() options

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

We are currently performing searches on a Database and returning results in JSON format to use on a Google Maps. The file that we call is named `getvenues.php` and works great on the server. It accepts a number of parameters and returns the results based on the query.

We then have a separate file that checks to see if there's a `JSON` file on the server which contains the results, matches its age against a setting, and then returns the data either from the cache file, or builds a new cache file if it's too old.

Since there are several thousand possible search options, we only cache single searches (either on a County, Region or Type). The JavaScript always calls our `search_cache_builder.php` file. If there is more than one search parameter, the file simply gets the contents returned by `getvenues.php` and serves it up without any caching.

Everything works great except for one particular combination. If a search is run for `venue_type=Castle / Fort` and `venue_name=Leeds Castle`, the `search_cache_builder.php` returns an empty array, even though accessing `getvenues.php` directly returns the required data.

Here's a sample of the `getvenues.php` working with this data > http://dev.weddingvenues.com/lincweb/getvenues.php?type=Castle%20/%20Fort&venue_name=Leeds%20Castle

And here's what the `search_cache_builder.php` script returns with an identical search (the address we are sending to is correct) > http://www.weddingvenues.com/search_cache_builder.php?type=castle%20/%20fort&venue_name=Leeds%20Castle

Here's the code for the `search_cache_builder.php` file, which relates to this particular query:

```
$get_string = '?';
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    if($get_string === '?')
    {
        $get_string .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $get_string .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
    }
}

//$get_string = str_replace(' ', '', $get_string);

// Otherwise, we need to serve up the page as is:
$file_url = GET_VEN_URL . $get_string;
echo file_get_contents($file_url);
```

Can anyone offer an explanation as to why the `search_cache_builder.php` file is returning an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `urlencode()` your parameter values.

In fact, while your getvenues.php receives parameters directly from a browser it behaves OK, 'cause they are correctly urlencoded.

I tried what follows in my computer towards your service and it works:

```
define ("GET_VEN_URL", "http://www.weddingvenues.com/getvenues.php");

$get_string = '?';
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    if($get_string === '?')
    {
        $get_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
    }
    else
    {
        $get_string .= '&' . $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
    }
}


$file_url = GET_VEN_URL . $get_string;
echo "<pre>";
echo $file_url;
echo "<pre>";

echo file_get_contents($file_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) values, then use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) to generate your get_string, your problem must be the special chars in values (like /).

Edit:
If you change the order it works: http://www.weddingvenues.com/search_cache_builder.php?venue_name=Leeds%20Castle&type=castle%20/%20fort

Comment: But running the search on only Castle / Fort works fine:
http://www.weddingvenues.com/search_cache_builder.php?type=castle%20/%20fort

Comment: Can be a double encoding, i edit this answer one second before your comment ;)

Comment: if you change the order it works: http://www.weddingvenues.com/search_cache_builder.php?venue_name=Leeds%20Castle&type=castle%20/%20fort (must be the encoding on the url)

Answer (score 0):

Because `$get_string === '?'` is ALWAYS false, change it to `==`, `?` is not a boolean.

I would not recommend using GET parameters, `&`,`?` as part of the file name.
Beside this,  it will quickly hit into 5k (or 4k, can not recall) limit for a file name.

You can do a sort by $GET, md5 (or hash) the array to a random string.
As long you ensure the hashing mechanism is consistent, you can easily retrieve the cache file.

Comment: Changing that line still doesn't work:
http://www.weddingvenues.com/search_cache_builder.php?type=castle%20/%20fort&venue_name=Leeds%20Castle

Comment: Of course... Just remember that there is no JSON encoding on the `search_cache_builder.php` file, so the empty array **must** be coming from the `getvenues.php` file...

Comment: No ... I dun know how you manage the results in getvenues.php. Given the only code you have enclosed is already fault, likely getvenues.php is faulty too. Why not you start by the simple one first, rollback all changes, and `var_dump($file_url);`?